# expo: eas local build failing

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

whenever I'm running this command `eas build -p ios --profile development --local` I'm getting an error :

```
Cocoapods is not available, make sure it's installed and in your PATH
pod --version exited with non-zero code: 1
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.
```

eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.13.3"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I made sure that cocoapods is installed correctly and available in PATH
`pod --version`  : `1.12.1`

`echo $PATH` : `/usr/local/bin`

The strange thing is that I made a local build a few days ago and it was successful without any issues.